# installing an application into Tomcat7 to run with sonarqube 4.1 (maven plugin)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, sonarqube

Could anyone tell me how to install applications into Tomcat for Sonarqube 4.1 please (or point me to some documentation as I'm failing to find it)

I have taken over some software I'm still learning about and I'm a bit confused about how the application/tomcat/sonarqube mechanism works.  Essentially in Jenkins on our build server I set up a different 'project' which used updated references of spring and elastic search.  I ran this and the old 'project' stopped working.  Eventually I tracked this down to the fact that the new version of the java project 'installed' into the base Tomcat directory (D:\Production\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF) and so now the 'running' version of the application Jenkins fires up to test against with a verify command has the wrong version of elastic search and so fails.  i.e. if I run

test sonar:sonar -Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true -Dacceptance

it runs fine but as the application code is solid but if I add -Dsonar.phase=verify it fails as the application currently installed into Tomcat is not .  I'm not sure how I managed to install the new code into Tomcat (perhaps this is automatic on running ?) but I wondered if anyone could tell me how I can safely remove the current version installed into Tomcat and replace it with the version being run by Jenkins now ?

I can't help feeling I must be missing some documentation somewhere but I just haven't found anything so any help would be appreciated!

Apologies if this is a bit garbled please ask for clarification if you think you can help!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube now embeds its own Tomcat server to run. It is the only supported mode.
There's no way to make SonarQube run on one your Tomcat servers.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies this was a bit of vague question asked in ignorance & hope.  I have realised now all this is being done by the maven cargo plugin and that for some reason cargo has stopped working.